# F# understanding discriminated union

Tags: f#

I've kind of asked this question earlier so sorry for asking a bit similar question again. But unfortunately im not able to really understand how to design a discriminated unions.

so i have bunch of data structures which look like

type Artist( artistId : int, name : String ) = 
    do
        if name = null then nullArg String.Empty
    new(artistId: int) = Artist(artistId)
    member x.ArtistId = artistId
    member x.Name = name

and Genre() = 
        let mutable name = String.Empty
        let mutable genreId : int = 0
        let mutable description = String.Empty
        let mutable albums = List.empty
        member x.Description 
            with get() = description and set( value ) = description <- value
        member x.Albums
            with get() = albums and set ( value ) = albums <- value

and Album() =
    let mutable title = String.Empty
    let mutable albumId = 0
    let mutable genreId = 0
    let mutable artistId = 0
    let mutable price : decimal = Decimal.Zero
    let mutable albumArtUrl = String.Empty
    let mutable genre = new Genre()
    let mutable artist = new Artist(artistId)
    member x.Title
        with get() = title and set (value) = title <- value
    member x.Genre
        with get() = genre and set (value) = genre <- value
    member x.AlbumId
        with get() = albumId and set ( value ) = albumId <- value
    member x.GenreId
        with get() = genreId and set ( value ) = genreId <- value
    member x.ArtistId
        with get() = artistId and set ( value ) = artistId <- value
    member x.Price
        with get() = price and set ( value ) = price <- value
    member x.AlbumArtUrl
        with get() = albumArtUrl and set ( value ) = albumArtUrl <- value 
    member x.Artist 
        with get() = artist and set ( value ) = artist <- value

enter code here

I tried defining the above as a Discriminated union based on suggestions by some of F# guru's

which i defined like below

type Name = string
type AlbumId = int

type Artist = 
    | ArtistId of int
    | Artist of Name

type Album = 
    | Title of string
    | Price of decimal
    | Album of AlbumId * Artist
    | AlbumArtUrl of string

type Genre = 
    | GenreId of int
    | Genre of Name * Album list

enter code here

But now i unable to figure out how would i populate my discriminated union similarly i was doing with my simple F# types which are just properties ?.

Can someone help me to explain this ?. I have been reading on discriminated unions but wont say i fully understand them .

Comment: In consideration of all the F# questions you've been asking lately, at this point it would really be worth your time to either read the Wikibook on F# <http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming> (written by the estimable @Juliet) or invest in a book on F#. Juliet's Wikibook is pretty good so you may want to start there. But no nastiness intended--you'd be wise to take some time and try to get some of the fundamentals down. I think you'll have a much better grasp of F# if you do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Discriminated unions are used to represent types with multiple different cases, which roughly corresponds to class hierarchies in object oriented langauges. For example, a base class `Shape` with two inherited classes for `Circle` and `Rectangle` might be defined like this:

```
type Shape = 
  | Rectangle of (float * float) * (float * float) // Carries locations of two corners
  | Circle of (float * float) * float              // Carries center and diameter
```

The way you defined your discriminated unions does not really do what you probably intended. Your types `Album`, `Artist` and `Genre` represent just a single concrete type.

You can represent these with either records (which are just like lightweight classes with just properties) or using discriminated unions **with a single case**, which corresponds to a single class, but has a pretty lightweight syntax, which is the main benefit. For example:

```
type Name = string  
type Price = decimal
type AlbumId = int  
type ArtistId = int  

type Artist = Artist of ArtistId * Name 
type Album = Album of AlbumId * Name * Price * Artist
```

To construct an artist together with a few albums, you can write:

```
let pinkFloyd = Artist(1, "Pink Floyd")

let darkSide = Album(1, "The Dark Side of the Moon", 12.0M, pinkFloyd)
let finalCut = Album(2, "The Final Cut", 11.0M, pinkFloyd)
```

If you then create a genre, that will contain a list of albums and possibly a list of artists, so you could write something like this:

```
type Genre = Genre of Name * Artist list * Album list 

let rock = Genre("Rock", [pinkFloyd], [darkSide; finalCut])
```

The question now is, how do you actually want to populate the types. What is your data-source? If you're loading data from a database or from a XML file, you're probably want to write a function that takes some part of the data source and returns `Artist` or `Album` and after you load all albums and artists, wrap them inside a `Genre` and return that as a final result.

PS: It is a bit difficult to answer your questions, because you're not really giving a bigger picture of what you're trying to do. If you can give a small, but concrete example (including the loading of data and their use), then someone can help you to look at the problem from a more functional perspective.

Comment: Oh really sorry @Tomas , i didnt meant to make my problem / question difficult to understand. All im trying is to follow this tutorial http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com, you can download the pdf if you like, which is in C# and convert the application to F#. Exact same application just want to learn functional programming / F# in the process.

Comment: You answer helped me quite a fair bit in understanding discriminated unions and what we can achieve by them. But how would i solve this problem when my types are mutually recursive. As Genre type also contains Album as a property. Is this possible when defining domains by using Discriminated unions?.

Comment: @netmatrix01 If you want to use mutually recursive types, then you'll generally need mutation and classes. However, do you really need to store reference from the `Album` to a `Genre` if your `Album`s are stored in a `Genre`? When you list e.g. albums in a specified genre, you'll always know the genre name. Similarly, when you display a specific album, you'll always know the genre if you walk through the object structure. So, I think I would probably try to avoid recursive structures in this kind of application.