# How to declare type as constrained in F#

Tags: f#

In Nodejs I could declare something like below ( note the productType ). Is this possible in a Record or struct in F#?  I don't want to use classes - and I don't think I can use enums because I want to store "S" or "G"

```
export interface Product {
    _id?: string
    sku: string
    name: string
    productType: 'S' | 'G' //S, G ( simple , grouped )
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [discriminated unions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/discriminated-unions).

Code will look like this:

```ml
type ProductType = Simple | Grouped

type Product =
    { Id   : string option // I don't know NodeJS, so I think that 'id?' is optional
      Sku  : string
      Name : string
      Type : ProductType }
```

Comment: you can use { Id : option<string> ......} instead of string option

Comment: @KenTsu `option<string>` is harder to write than `string option` and also it's against [guideline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/style-guide/formatting#use-prefix-syntax-for-generics-foot-in-preference-to-postfix-syntax-t-foo)

Answer (score 0):

- you could use [Discriminated Unions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/discriminated-unions) for S & G union

```
[<Struct>]
type SingleCase = Case of string

[<Struct>]
type Multicase =
    | Case1 of Case1 : string
    | Case2 of Case2 : int
    | Case3 of Case3 : double
```

- [Discriminated unions are used to represent types with multiple different cases, which roughly corresponds to class hierarchies in object oriented langauges.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9194883/15073910)